# "Remake" NSString 2d array

Tags: ios, arrays, string, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reset array after playing the game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883853/reset-array-after-playing-the-game)

I made a 2d array:

```
NSString *arrEurope[][2] =

{

    {@"Eifel.jpg",@"Paris"},
    {@"NotreDame.jpg",@"Paris"},
    {@"ArcDeTriompheParis.jpg",@"Paris"},

    {@"AtomuimBrussels.jpg",@"Brussels"},
    {@"MannekePis.jpg",@"Brussels"},

    {@"Colosseum.jpg",@"Rome"},
    {@"TreviFountainRome.jpg",@"Rome"},

    {@"SagradaFamilia.jpg",@"Barcelona"},
    {@"SpanishSchoolMadrid.jpg",@"Madrid"},

    {@"KremlinMoskou.jpg",@"Moskou"},

    {@"MermaidKopenhagen.jpg",@"Copenhagen"},

    {@"MonteCarloMonaco.jpg",@"Monaco"},

    {@"AcropolisAthens.jpg",@"Athens"},

    {@"ParlementBudapest.jpg",@"Budapest"},

    {@"BuildingReykjavik.jpg",@"Reykjavik"},

    {@"StatueKiev.jpg",@"Kiev"},

    {@"PortOfEuropeLissabon.jpg",@"Lisbon"},

    {@"ViewSanMarino.jpg",@"San Marino"},

    {@"BridgesPrague.jpg",@"Prague"},

    {@"MoskeeAnkara.jpg",@"Ankara"},

    {@"TowerBridgeLondon.jpg",@"London"},
    {@"BigBenLondon.jpg",@"London"},
    {@"LondonEyeLondon.jpg",@"London"},

    {@"BrandenburgerTor.jpg",@"Berlin"},
    {@"ReichstagBerlin.jpg",@"Berlin"},

    {nil,nil}

};
```

Now, in my code i change some of the content of the array like this:

```
arrEurope[intRandomMonument][0] = @"removed";
```

Now when i use a restart button, i want to be the array back like it is above, but instead of that it's full of "removed".
Someone can help me? Thank you and sorry about the bad english :)

(The Array works and the "removed" thing is for making sure that that item isn't called back in a current game so all the code works but i just want to 'reset' the array.)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you're trying to use C style arrays?

I recommend using [`NSArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) instead.

```
NSArray *arrEurope = @[@[@"Eifel.jpg",@"Paris"],
                       @[@"NotreDame.jpg",@"Paris"],
                       @[@"ArcDeTriompheParis.jpg",@"Paris"]
                       ... etc ... ];
```

Comment: Are there many changes that i have to make or just replace the NSString with NSArray and the content of it? And how would it be if i use the NSArray? (i know it makes more sense to use the NSArray, but i'm new to IOS programming :)

Comment: Do what I did. Fix the syntax. And yes, usually it makes more sense to use `NSArray`. Memory management will be a lot easier like that. And your code should work with that (setting "removed").

Comment: I used the array like you said above, but i got the error:
initializer element is not a compile-time constant.
and how can i for example get NotreDame.jpg out of my array? i guess its not arrEurope[1][0]?

Comment: It should work. Your syntax is probably wrong. Did you maybe forget a comma or bracket?

Comment: And yes, you can access NotreDame.jpg like that. `arrEurope[1][0]` will be replaced by `[[arrEurope objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:0]` when you compile. These are methods of the `NSArray` class. You can read about them in the documentation.

Comment: Maybe is my end code wrong, in the nsstring i end with nil,nil

Comment: You don't need `nil` endings with that syntax for NSArray.

Comment: You only need that if you use the old method syntax: `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"str1", @"str2", nil];`, but not with the new literals: `@[@"str1", @"str"];`.

Comment: cause i don't know where my fault is i'll show you my (short)array:
[code]
NSArray *arrEurope = @[
@[@"Eifel.jpg",@"Paris"],
@[@"NotreDame.jpg",@"Paris"]
];

[code]

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? The NSArray literals are only available since 4.4.